# Config to make Kafka client.id required

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

client.id in Kafka consumers is optional, so is there any way that can force consumers to set it before connecting and consuming messages?

Answer (score 2):

Not built-in, no.

You can create a wrapper library around Kafka client creation that enforces this, but then you need to enforce others to use this as well.

---

If you are instead looking for ways to identify client requests, sounds like you want authorization rather than plain-strings that could come from anywhere/anyone